# Image not uploaded, while the API call (via PATCH method) is successful, Alamofire, Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I want to upload an image to the server using an API which operates on patch method, API also needs an authentication token.

```
Alamofire.upload(
                multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

                    for (key, value) in params {
                        if let image = value as? UIImage {
                            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7) {
                                MultipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "file\(arc4random()).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                            }
                        }else {
                            MultipartFormData.append(String(describing: value).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                        }
                    }

            }, to:url, method: .patch, headers: ["content-type":"application/json","token": authToken]) { (result) in

                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                            print(response.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error while requesting")
                            completionHandler(nil)
                            return
                        }
                        if let value = response.result.value {
                            let json = JSON(value)
                            print(json)
                        }else {
                            completionHandler(nil)
                        }
                    }

                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
```

Problem is that `API` call is successful but Image is not uploaded on the server, Please Help me out here.

Thank you

Comment: check imageData is nill or not?

Comment: checked...imageData not nil

Comment: May be image key name is different

Comment: @VirajSingh do you get answer your question?\